# Why do we write A.charAt(i) but not A.charAt[i]? And why do we write " - 'A' "?

Tags: java, charat

```
public static int get(String A) // it is a method
{
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++) // So A reads line (any word, for example "Car"), so I understand that length will be 3 and that java will check all the characters.

        {
            int num = (A.charAt(i) - 'A') + 1;
            count *= num;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Because `String#charAt()` is a method, not an array instance. You write 'A' to indicate a type `char`, as opposed to "A" which is a `String`.

Comment: @barakmanos just edit it if the spelling bothers you. And then put the rest of the comment which is clearly an answer in the answer section.

Comment: @weston: It doesn't realy bother me, I just figured that OP would notice it if I commented instead of editing. As to answering it, there are already about 10 answers here (as expected). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *write* `A.charAt(i)` because `charAt` is a function, not an array.

You write `A.charAt(i) - 'A'` to compute the difference between `A`'s `i`:th character and the character `'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

The class `String` is an [immutable or value object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). It doesn't give you direct access to the characters which make up the string, mainly for performance reasons but also since it helps to avoid a whole class of bugs.

That's why you can't use the array access via `[]`. You could call `A.getChars()` but that would create a *copy* of the underlying character array.

`char` is the code for a character. `'A' == 65`, for example. See [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/). If `A.charAt(1)` returns `'F'` (or 70), then `'F' - 'A'` gives you 5. +1 gives 6.

So the code above turns letters into a number. A pattern which you'll see pretty often is `charAt(i) - '0'` to turn a string into a number.

But the code above is odd in this respect since `count *= num` produces a pretty random result for the input. To turn the letters into numbers, base 26, it should read `count = count * 26 + num`.

Answer (score 0):

because charAt() is a method in java for string it and it returns a character. and 'A' refers to a char type while we write "A" for string type
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

`A.charAt(i)` is a method for strings, you could also do `A[i]` to access the same position directly.

When you do an operation (+ or -) with chars, you get an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

[**Java API for charAt() function**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

> **[charAt()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) is a java method, not an Array**
>
> returns the char value at the specified index.

**Syntax:**

Here is the syntax of this method:

```
public char charAt(int index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `charAt()` is a method that returns a character from a given String, and not an array. Characters are written `'A'`. Strings are written `"A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Because [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) is a method within string and it accepts index. String internally maintains char array and it's all hidden from us and hence you have a method not the array itself.

Reason for `-'A'` is user wants to convert that character to integer. So for e.g. You character is 'B', User wants to convert it into int using `ascii value of 'B' which is 66 - ascii value of 'A' which 65`

```
num = 66 - 65 + 1
```

And do further processing.